# Mapping private set using NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate

In my class i have the following property:

```
Class A
{
    public virtual string Tag
        {
            get; private set;
        }
}
```

And in my hbm.xml i have the following (which does not work)

```
<property name="Tag" access="nosetter.camelcase" />
```

Nhibernate can't find the backing field. Does anybody known which access strategy to use (if any)??? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would like the setter to be private for encapsulation. It is the same as using an explicit filed tag and setting that in the class. I want the property to be read-only.

Comment: @Gluip don't think that is the same as an explicit field setting.  any reason not to have an explicit field ?

Comment: No other reason than less code is less trouble. Now switched to an explicit field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using access property you need to have backing field for this public property. And also use protected modifier instead of private.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure that's having to be public.

There could be something done with explicit private fields and possibly another variable, but would want to know why you want the setter to be private ?